# Why isn't Pluto a circle on LORRI images?

Tags: new-horizons, pluto

A Long Distance Look from LORRI images [were published recently](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/News-Center/News-Article.php?page=20150204).

Pluto and Charon look like shrunken ovals here:

[image]

Why is this?

Is it due to Pluto and Charon's phases? Is the distance enough to observe not full phase?

I calculated that since the speed of Pluto is 4.6 km/s and the speed of New Horizons is 14.6 km/s, then the angle it observed is 17 degrees.

[image]

Is this correct and is this enough to observe not full phase?

Comment: Your diagram is wrong because speed is a scalar quantity, but you're using it as a vector (assuming it describes both magnitude and direction). Also, only the hypotenuse can be a straight line in this case. Here is [New Horizon's current position and trajectory](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Mission/Where-is-New-Horizons/index.php). The Sun-spacecraft-Pluto angles are [nearly in a straight line](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/whereisnh/overview/nhov20150201_0193.jpg).

Comment: Speed is a scalar quantity? When did God declared that?

Comment: On the very first day, according to Genesis 1:3

Comment: @Dims *velocity* is a vector. Speed is a scalar.

Comment: @TildalWave okay God was speaking English and was... American? Will know this. Now. Why do you think this is vector diagram?

Comment: I have improved diagram for people not think there some vectors there

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per New Horizons science team member John Spencer, [via Emily Lakdawalla](https://twitter.com/elakdawalla/status/563376682497605632), the spacecraft is [not yet close enough](http://astro.cornell.edu/academics/courses/astro201/diff_limit.htm) to fully resolve the the shapes of Pluto and Charon.  Their apparent shape is dominated by the camera / telescope's [point spread function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function), which is "slightly teardrop shaped, giving that gibbous appearance".

Comment: Can you also explain the latest photos? They all have a kind of smear effect artefacts

Comment: @rubo77 If you're referring to [these photos](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/News-Center/News-Article.php?page=20150512) they're both heavily processed (which can cause various artifacts depending on the type of processing, which they have not detailed) and overexposed (which causes CCD [blooming and streaking](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/digitalimaging/concepts/ccdsatandblooming.html)).

Comment: [Here](http://www.nasa.gov/newhorizons/lorri-gallery) the pictures have all those Streaks to the right